# partition a list into sub list based on size of sub list

Tags: java

i have a list of users increasing dynamically and want to divide them to multiple contact person equally of size say 5 each in java.Keeping in mind if contact person has not complete first 5 should not be assigned more or if completed 1 can be assigned 1 next time on new user added to list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The logic you describe is not straightforward to implement. When the contact person "complete" with a user? Can a contact person be represented as a thread?

Comment: @marc contact person is just a contact_id .